# PSD matrices with identical diagonal elements

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalue, eigenvector

How to construct two positive semi definite matrices with identical diagonal elements? Suppose M1 and M2 are tow psd matrices.  I want vectors of diagonal( M1 ) and diagonal( M2 ) to be identical. Off-diagonal elements have to be different.

```
[a e f g]  [a s t u]  
[e b h i]  [s b v w]
[f h c j]  [t v c x]
[g i j d]  [u w x d]
```

consider the first matrix as M1 and second as M2. To keep in mind that both M1 and M2 are PSD.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One way is like this, in 2d: start with a PSD matrix P and then compute

```
M1 = P + e(a)*e(a)' + f(a)*f(a)'
M2 = P + e(b)*e(b)' + f(b)*f(b)'
```

where 
  e(a) = (cos(a), sin(a))'
  f(a) = (sin(a), cos(a))'

For example if P is 0 we get

```
M1 = ( 1       sin(2a))
     (sin(2a)  1 )
M2 = ( 1        sin(2b))
     (sin(2b)   1      )
```

so you can choose a,b so that M1 and M2 are different.

For larger matrices you could do several such steps, using for example
e(a) = ( 0 cos(a) 0 0 sin(a))' etc in a step to make the (1,4) and (4,1) entries different